# Contentful preview api using angular project

Tags: contentful, contentful-management

Please let me know how to use preview functionality with preview token using Angular. Found preview api using next js but looking for angular

Found way using next js but looking for preview with angular.

Angular with CDN content also able to achieve but looking exclusively for preview API with angular